# Can not import module: You may need an appropriate loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, bower

I have a React project using `bower` and `webpack`.

I am trying to use this module https://github.com/jrowny/react-absolute-grid.

I installed it with npm and I added it to my code like this:

```
import AbsoluteGrid from 'react-absolute-grid/lib/AbsoluteGrid.jsx';
```

When importing the module, I get this issue:

```
Line 3: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 'use strict';
|
| import React from 'react';
```

I suspect the problem is that within `webpack.config.js` I only load files from where my code is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

However, I'm not sure.

I saw questions with a similar error message on SO but they had other issues as far as I could see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the way you import the module:

From:

```
import AbsoluteGrid from 'react-absolute-grid/lib/AbsoluteGrid.jsx';
```

To:

```
import AbsoluteGrid from 'react-absolute-grid';
```

And you should better exclude `node_modules` and `bower_components` in webpack configs:

```
...
loader: 'babel-loader',
exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
```

Also, you should better use [`babel-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) with [`react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) and [`es2015`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) babel presets.

Install them:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015
```

And inclue in webpack configs:

```
module : {
  loaders : [
    {
      test : /\.jsx?/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }
  ]  
}
```